# Proper jruby syntax for requiring java and including java classes

Tags: syntax, jruby

I can't seem to find what the current syntax for using java classes in Jruby is.
This [link text](http://blogs.oracle.com/coolstuff/entry/using_java_classes_in_jruby) article lists:

```
include Java
include 'java'
require 'java'
```

As valid options, though it says the last option is pre 1.0 and doesn't work.
The [Jruby Wiki](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/CallingJavaFromJRuby) however says to use `require 'java'`

And for including classes I've seen

```
MyClass = Java::some.package.MyClass
include_class Java::some.package.MyClass
include_class 'some.package.MyClass'
java_import Java::some.package.MyClass
```

Is there one preferred method?

Currently I'm getting some "redefining X" message as I have a few java classes named the same as my ruby class.  What's the best method for keeping the java namespace so I don't get these, and are there any issues (aside from the obvious Java class taking precedent to the ruby class) with this redefinition if I never use the two ruby/java classes in the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer

```
require 'java'
java_import java.lang.System
```

I think the choice of `require 'java'` is not that import and is just personal preference. On the other hand, [JRubyWiki](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/CallingJavaFromJRuby#Accessing_and_Importing_Java_Classes) says `java_import` is preferred, due to [this bug report](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-3171).

For the name conflict between Java and JRuby classes. For the sake of code readability or for maintenance purpose, I'd suggest to avoid using the same Name for 2 different classes, unless you mean to re-open it.

**Update**: are you sure the error 'Redefine X ...' is caused by having the same name for your Java and JRuby class? I usually get this error because I `java_import` the same Java class multiple times (sometimes in different places, sometime I load the same file multiple times).

Comment: ya it appears to be clashing.  When I instantiate an object that includes a bunch of java classes (only once) I get that message.  I have a ruby "Supplier" class and I also include a "new.my_app.Supplier" java class with include_class

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I always use `require 'java'`

If you're having namespace clashes, I'd suggest not including or importing, but specifying fully qualified class names, e.g.

`my_instance = Java::JavaUtil::Date.new`

...where `Java::` is top level module for all java classes, `JavaUtil::` is the full package name for the class I want, in proper-case and jammed together, and `Date` is the actual class name.